# Insert NA-rows in data frame according to rownames of other data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have 2 data frames with different rownames, e.g.:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1,3,7,1,5), B = c(5,2,9,5,5), C = c(1,1,3,4,5))
df2 <- data.frame(A = c(4,3,2), B = c(4,4,9), C = c(3,9,3))
rownames(df2) <- c(1, 3, 6)

> df1
  A B C
1 1 5 1
2 3 2 1
3 7 9 3
4 1 5 4
5 5 5 5

> df2
  A B C
1 4 4 3
3 3 4 9
6 2 9 3
```

I need to insert NA-rows in both data frames for each row that does exist in only one of the data frames. In the given example:

```
> df1
  A  B  C
1 1  5  1
2 3  2  1
3 7  9  3
4 1  5  4
5 5  5  5
6 NA NA NA

> df2
  A  B  C
1 4  4  3
2 NA NA NA
3 3  4  9
4 NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA
6 2  9  3
```

I will have to perform this operation many times with different data frames, so I need an automatized way to do this. I was trying to solve the issue with different if/else loops, but I am sure there must be a much more automatized way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use functions `union`, `%in%` or `intersect` to find the common rownames and assign rows of an NA dataframe with the values of the dataset if it matches the rownames

```
un1 <- union(rownames(df1), rownames(df2))
d1  <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(df1), 
        nrow = length(un1), dimnames = list(un1, names(df1))))
d2 <- d1
d1[rownames(d1) %in% rownames(df1),]  <- df1
d2[rownames(d2) %in% rownames(df2),] <- df2
d2
#   A  B  C
#1  4  4  3
#2 NA NA NA
#3  3  4  9
#4 NA NA NA
#5 NA NA NA
#6  2  9  3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the perfect answer!